# exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type: Mage_Catalog_Block_Category_List'

Tags: magento, exception, block, categories

I'm getting the following error in my exception.log repeatedly.  Any suggestions for troubleshooting and tracking it down?  I have not had any success in determining the problem.

```
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type: Mage_Catalog_Block_Category_List' in /chroot/home/mysite/mywebsite/html/app/Mage.php:550
Stack trace:
#0 /chroot/home/mysite/mywebsite/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(469): Mage::throwException('Invalid block t...')
#1 /chroot/home/mysite/mywebsite/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(411): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('catalog/categor...', Array)
#2 /chroot/home/mysite/mywebsite/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(446): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('catalog/categor...', 'catalog.categor...')
#3 /chroot/home/mysite/mywebsite/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(238): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('catalog/categor...', 'catalog.categor...')
#4 /chroot/home/mysite/mywebsite/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(204): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#5 /chroot/home/mysite/mywebsite/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(209): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#6 /chroot/home/mysite/mywebsite/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(343): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#7 /chroot/home/mysite/mywebsite/html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/controllers/ProductController.php(115): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#8 /chroot/home/mysite/mywebsite/html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/controllers/ProductController.php(149): Mage_Catalog_ProductController->_initProductLayout(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product))
#9 /chroot/home/mysite/mywebsite/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Catalog_ProductController->viewAction()
#10 /chroot/home/mysite/mywebsite/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('view')
#11 /chroot/home/mysite/mywebsite/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(177): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#12 /chroot/home/mysite/mywebsite/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(304): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#13 /chroot/home/mysite/mywebsite/html/app/Mage.php(596): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#14 /chroot/home/mysite/mywebsite/html/index.php(78): Mage::run('', 'store')
#15 {main}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does

```
Mage_Catalog_Block_Category_List
```

exist as a class in either:

```
app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Category
```

or

```
app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block/Category
```

I am running Magento 1.7 and cannot locate that class. Perhaps you are looking for:

```
Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List
```

Comment: yep or Mage_Catalog_Block_Category_View . You must have mis-typed a block in your xml layout. Search for "catalog/category" in catalog.xml layout file

Comment: Thank you!  I found the offending code under the section for "Catalog Product View (Any)"
I just commented it out for now.  It looks like someone was trying follow this thread but never finished it correctly.  There was no corresponding phtml file.  http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/9632/